# Array access not allowed on OpenFL movieclips

Tags: haxe, openfl

**UDATED**

How do I go about this?

I got this from `Main.hx`:

```
function onMouseOver(e:MouseEvent){
     if(Std.is(e.currentTarget, MovieClip)){
         initializer (cast e.currentTarget,["scaleX",1.5,"scaleY",1.5])
     }
}
```

Then this is the pointed function in my Animation Class

```
//here if i set mc:Dynamic everything goes great! but when this one

function initializer(mc:MovieClip, vars:Array<Dynamic>){
       var varsLength:Int = Math.round(vars.length/2);

       for(m in 0...varsLength){

            ini[m] = mc[vars[2*m]];

       }
}
```

then when i compile it, an error appears:

> **Error**: Array access is not allowed in flash.display.MovieClip

How do I resolve this?

EDIT:

vars: are properties of the MovieClip, for example when I pass these parameters:

```
initializer (mcClip1,["scaleX",1.5,"scaleY",1.5])
```

so:

```
vars = ["scaleX",1.5,"scaleY",1.5]
```

and:

```
ini[m] will store "scaleX" and "scaleY"`
```

X-Ref: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haxelang/_hkyt__Rrzw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In AS3, you can access fields of an object via their String name using `[]` (array access). This is called *Reflection*.

In Haxe, [`Reflection` works differently](http://haxe.org/manual/std-reflection.html) - you need to make use of the [Reflect API](http://api.haxe.org/Reflect.html).

It's considered bad practice - it's not type-safe, which means the compiler can do very little to help you with error messages, and it's quite slow as well. This is why the usage makes it very explicit that Reflection is actually going on (while in AS3, this fact is somewhat hidden). **Consider if there are other ways of solving this problem that don't require Reflection.**

Now, to get back to your example, here's what it would look like in Haxe:

```
function onMouseOver(e:MouseEvent){
     if (Std.is(e.currentTarget, MovieClip)) {
         initializer(cast e.currentTarget, ["scaleX", 1.5, "scaleY", 1.5])
     }
}

function initializer(mc:MovieClip, vars:Array<Dynamic>) {
       for (m in 0...Std.int(vars.length / 2)) {
            ini[m] = Reflect.getProperty(mc, vars[2*m]);
       }
}
```

Btw, your loop was running for too long since you only use half of the values in the array - if you don't divide it by two like I did, you'll end up with `[scaleX, scaleY, null, null]` instead of the desired `[scaleX, scaleY]`.

Comment: I made an edit. The vars.length is divided by 2 in my original code and still caused the error. The Reflection may just be accidental from my coding, I would like to avoid it in as much as possible. How do I resolve the error and avoiding reflection. Its seams that using mc:Dynamic against mc:MovieClip resolved the matter, but it does not become cross-platform compatible for export to html5.

Comment: It seems my code look like reflection, are there work around to not using reflection?

Comment: Hi, I think you have answer my question correctly, avoiding reflection was another issue, what I was trying to do is enlarge all "important" movie clips on stage upon mouse over. I have not solved it since.